# Django CMS - Multilanguage setup translates plugins in edit mode

Tags: django, django-cms

I am using django-cms version 3.7.1 with multilanguage setup.
Default and admin user language is set to english 'en', second one is German 'de'.

Everything is running ok (url, editing content for each language), except one detail - admin user language is set to English, so toolbar menu is always English, but when i switch to edit page content in deutch, plugin modal window with editor show german translation for buttons etc.

Is that supposed to work that way? Now plugin text is always changing according to page language (if i add spanish for example, button will be in spanish).

I need plugins to have text in language admin user have in own settings. In this case always English.. even when editing German page.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

[Screenshot how it look like in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mraiC.png)

Comment: Have you got the javascript catalog view in your URLs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n

Comment: I installed django-cms 3.7.1 with djangoinstaller. According to: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/languages.html, it should be already set up, but i dont see JavaScriptCatalog in my urls.py. But even if i ad those urlpatterns nothing change. Plugin button language is still dependent on page i am on rather than my admin lanugage setting.